# How to compare these data sets from a csv? Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a project where I'm trying to create a program that will take a csv data set from www.transtats.gov which is a data set for airline flights in the US. My goal is to find the flight from one airport to another that had the worst delays overall, meaning it is the "worst flight". So far I have this:

```
`import csv
    with open('826766072_T_ONTIME.csv') as csv_infile: #import and open CSV
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_infile)
    total_delay = 0
    flight_count = 0
    flight_numbers = []
    delay_totals = []
    dest_list = [] #create empty list of destinations
    for row in reader:
        if row['ORIGIN'] == 'BOS': #only take flights leaving BOS
            if row['FL_NUM'] not in flight_numbers:
                flight_numbers.append(row['FL_NUM'])
            if row['DEST'] not in dest_list: #if the dest is not already in the list
                 dest_list.append(row['DEST']) #append the dest to dest_list
    for number in flight_numbers:
        for row in reader:
            if row['ORIGIN'] == 'BOS': #for flights leaving BOS
                if row['FL_NUM'] == number:
                    if float(row['CANCELLED']) < 1: #if the flight is not cancelled
                        if float(row['DEP_DELAY']) >= 0: #and the delay is greater or equal to 0 (some flights had negative delay?)
                            total_delay += float(row['DEP_DELAY']) #add time of delay to total delay
                            flight_count += 1 #add the flight to total flight count
    for row in reader:
        for number in flight_numbers:
                delay_totals.append(sum(row['DEP_DELAY']))`
```

I was thinking that I could create a list of flight numbers and a list of the total delays from those flight numbers and compare the two and see which flight had the highest delay total. What is the best way to go about comparing the two lists?

Comment: Could you show an example of the lists you want to compare. This might help you, and others to spot a simple solution.

Comment: From a statistical basis I can see an issue calculating total delay because more frequent flights may get a higher total delay even if the delay per flight is quite short. Instead of sum can you do an average?

Comment: That is true. I should be calculating the average delay to account for more or less flights for each flight number. For an average I would still need the sum and just total the number of flights and do a simple total delay / total flights correct?

Comment: Alternatively you can just append all the delays for a certain flight to a list and average them at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but I think you should use `dict` for this purpose, where key is a `'FL_NUM'` and value is total delay.

Answer (score 1):

In general I want to eliminate loops in Python code. For files that aren't massive I'll typically read through a data file once and build up some `dict`s that I can analyze at the end. The below code isn't tested because I don't have the original data but follows the general pattern I would use.

Since a flight is identified by the origin, destination, and flight number I would capture them as a `tuple` and use that as the key in my dict.

```
from collections import defaultdict
flight_delays = defaultdict(list) # look this up if you aren't familiar 
for row in reader:
    if row['ORIGIN'] == 'BOS': #only take flights leaving BOS
        if row['CANCELLED'] > 0:
             flight = (row['ORIGIN'], row['DEST'], row['FL_NUM'])
             flight_delays[flight].append(float(row['DEP_DELAY']))


# Finished reading through data, now I want to calculate average delays
worst_flight = ""
worst_delay = 0
for flight, delays in flight_delays.items():
    average_delay = sum(delays) / len(delays)
    if average_delay > worst_delay:
        worst_flight = flight[0] + " to " + flight[1] + " on FL#" + flight[2]
        worst_delay = average_delay
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution would be. Adding two new variables:

```
max_delay = 0
delay_flight = 0
# Change: if float(row['DEP_DELAY']) >= 0: FOR:
if float(row['DEP_DELAY']) > max_delay:
  max_delay = float(row['DEP_DELAY'])
  delay_flight = #save the row number or flight number for reference.
```

Comment: Could I also do max_delay = sum(float(row['DEP_DELAY']))? Each flight number has more than one delay associated with it and I would like to get the total of those delays.

Comment: Sure you can. Would be advisable to compute the total delay store it in a temporal variable the compare with max_delay. And if greater update the value of max_delay.